# Difficulties setting up a color ramp on joined data (QGIS 3.20)

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to join a couple of datasets together, one of them in a QGIS shapefile, one from outside, and than use one of the outside datasets to create a color gradient.However, various steps in the process haven't worked in weird ways.  (So, shapefile  join to otherfile, than display color from a gradient based on the value of otherfile variable x.)

Try 1:  I joined the data in an outside program, and copied over one of the files linked to the shapefile.  This seemed to work, after lots of messing around (missing data, the map not showing up, and such.), but the resulting color gradient was often either missing data or showing something totally different from what it should have shown.  (At first it was random, than I got it kind of figured out by sorting the data properly.)

Try 2:  Joined the two pieces in QGIS using the join system.  The join worked properly, but the new variables did not allow me to even create a gradient.

Is there some standardized way of doing all these steps?  (Python could probably do it, but since I'm doing a lot of these a faster method is worthwhile.)

Comment: At least to me, the question is unclear. It would help to see a screenshot - or even more if you could share your data and project files (also with dummy data only).

Comment: Which data type does the field have you're trying to create the colour ramp with?

Comment: Turns out it was the wrong data type, as Erik said.  Figured it out the night after asking the question, and changing the data types in the CSV file to number from string made it work.  I uploaded through the menu using a text delimited option to get it to automatically go string instead of clicking in the side box, but presumably any method would work.